# Finding percentile ranks for questionnaires and psychometric tests

Tags: measurement, personality, test

I am using a Levenson's Self-Report Psychopathy Scale to divide participants into two groups (high v low scores). I have selected participants based on them scoring in the top or bottom 25% of responses. I would like to report the mean percentile rank that each group falls under. I am relatively new to using psychological tests and don't know where to find this information. Is this available somewhere for all validated tests?

Comment: I am not aware of any single database encompassing all validated tests (“validated” isn’t even an agreed upon term), especially not with regular updates. Publishers typically have special departments offering support and resources to researchers, so that may answer your question for other tests. This one is open-source so you’d have to manually dig through research, and/or contact the original author/lab or closest alternative for further guidance.